# Battery charger RT9471 is not cutting off voltage on VSYS pin in ship mode

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, charger, voltage

I am using RT9471 battery charger. It enters ship mode when battery voltage reaches 3.0 V through I2C communication. The battery is connected to PCM IC (AP9221SA-CC-HAC-7) and then to battery charger.

[image]

When I checked the current consumption from battery while in ship mode, it showed 0.27 mA discharge current. The voltage at VSYS pin is 1.2 V.

[image]

**In the datasheet of Battery charger it is as below.**

[image]

Now if BATFET is turned OFF in ship mode, **why am I getting 1.2 V on VSYS pin of the battery charger?**

## Schematic

[image]
[image]

*Battery charger (RT9471) Datasheet:* https://www.richtek.com/RedirectToProduct?specid=RT9471/RT9471D

*PCM IC (AP9221SA-CC-HAC-7) Datasheet:* https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/115/DIOD_S_A0012884324_1-2543822.pdf